# MySQL query variables in node

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm having trouble with this query in NodeJS.

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT POSITION FROM (
    SELECT name, @i:=@i+1 AS POSITION
    FROM database.table ti WHERE name='Johny' ORDER BY points ASC) t WHERE name='Johny'
```

Query works in Heidi SQL without a problem, but when i execute it in Node, i get callback is undefined.

NodeJS code :

```
var query =
          "SET @i = 0;"
        + " SELECT POSITION FROM ("
        + "     SELECT name, @i:=@i+1 AS POSITION"
        + " FROM database.table ti WHERE name='Johny' ORDER BY points ASC) t WHERE name='Johny'";
mySQLconnection.query(query,function(err,rows){
    console.log(rows);
});
```

Thank You in advance,

Comment: could you show us your query that you execute in heidi?

Comment: SET @i = 0;
SELECT POSITION FROM (
SELECT name, @i:=@i+1 AS POSITION
FROM test_database.test_table ti WHERE name='Johny' ORDER BY points ASC) t WHERE name='Johny'

Comment: This will return the position of the result in the result set. For example : If 'Johny' is in second row in result set it will return '2' in POSITION column

Comment: You can put the Query inside a procedure and call the it .

Answer (score 8):

i search this post by google and i found the reason why variables not work
try this it's work for me:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

by default node-mysql will only execute only one query on time
if you've enabled the multipleStatements on create connect setting then your code should work.
hope it work for you.

Comment: This may lead to an SQL Injection attack , refer https://www.npmjs.com/package//mysql#multiple-statement-queries

Answer (score 2):

I had to run the queries separately to get them to work.

E.g.,

```
var config = {user: "root", password: "root"}; // your config
var sql1 = "SET @i = 0";
var sql2 = " SELECT POSITION FROM ( " +
    "SELECT name, @i:=@i+1 AS POSITION " +
    "FROM database.table ti WHERE name='Johny' ORDER BY points ASC) t " +
    "WHERE name='Johny'";

var result = [];
var connection = mysql.createConnection(config);

var query1 = connection.query(sql1);
query1.on("error", function (err) {
    // handle error
});
query1.on("end", function () {
    var query2 = connection.query(sql2);
    query2.on("error", function (err) {
        // handle error
    });
    query2.on("result", function (row) {
        result.push(row);
    });
    query2.on("end", function () {
        connection.end(); // close connection
        console.log(result); // display result
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have been searching for this for a year. Thanks you. I wonder why it never showed up. For some reason the SET @variable wasn't working with all suggestions made elsewhere. Yours worked flawlessly.

Comment: Glad it helped 

Answer (score 0):

solution:
you don't have to use the @x or @y, it won't work in node-mysql
you must use this.

`SELECT * from (SELECT * as column1 FROM table1) as x, (Select * as column2 From table2) as y)`;

this works for me.